# How to observe text change in UITextField using RxSwift?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to observe any change of the `UITextField.text` property using RxSwift.

I trying to use `rx.text` property, but it called only when I set `text` property like this: `textField.text = ""`, but not working when I typing text.

Also I tried to use `rx.observe(String.self, "text")`, but it gives the same result.

How can I observe any change of the text in UITextField?

Answer (score 11):

To observe any change of the text in `UITextField` you can create extension for `Reactive` class:

```
public extension Reactive where Base: UITextField {

    public var textChange: Observable<String?> {
        return Observable.merge(self.base.rx.observe(String.self, "text"),
                                self.base.rx.controlEvent(.editingChanged).withLatestFrom(self.base.rx.text))
    }

}
```